# Banco de Dados - Relacionamento - Pesquisa

Tags: python, banco-de-dados, django

Olá, pessoal, estou fazendo um projeto Django e tenho uma dúvida quanto a modelagem das entidades. No meu projeto uma pessoa pode assumir vários cadastros. Um dia ela pode ser vendedora da empresa, mas no outro dia ela pode estar de folga (ou mesmo não ser mais funcionária da empresa) e pode ser cliente da empresa. Desse modo, ela terá dois tipos de cadastro na empresa. Quando eu for fazer a buscar pelo nome da pessoa, quero obter todos os registros dela como vendedora e todos os registros como cliente.

Normalmente, os esquemas de modelagem trazem tabelas separadas Vendedor e Cliente. Mas, desse jeito, se eu for fazer a busca pelo nome da pessoa tenho que pegar o nome e percorrer a tabela Vendedor e verificar se o nome consta lá e também percorrer a tabela cliente. Para esse sistema, é normal, comum, ter essas tabelas em separado? Há uma outra forma mais adequada.

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Pelo que descreveu, parece que está falando de uma vendedora "Avon" que é cliente e vendedora, mas pode ser que não faça vendas num mês, certo? Você poderia criar uma Classe de modelo abstrata contendo tipo booleano ativa no mês ou não e com um campo de atualização auto preenchido pra toda vez que atualizar

Comment: Obrigado, Carlos Cortez, pela sugestão. Porém, a princípio, encontrei uma possível solução na documentação do django por meio do OneToOneField, no link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/. No meu caso, criaria uma tabela para Pessoa e outras para Vendedor e Cliente. Primeiro, cadastro a pessoa, que eventualmente pode ser vendedor e/ou cliente.